# Distance between two knots

Tags: reference-request, gt.geometric-topology, knot-theory

Are there some well-studied functions defining natural distance measures between two knots? One can imagine a function that counts, say, the minimum number of
moves, each of which passes one strand of a knot through a crossing strand, in order to convert one knot to another.
Or perhaps there are functions that rely on knot polynomial similarity.

Any references would be appreciated.

---

***Update***. Here is a figure from the Murakami reference kindly provided by Marco Golla:

---

[image]

          

<sup>(Murakami Fig.7, illustrating *#-unknotting operations*.)</sup>

---

> Murakami, Hitoshi. "Some metrics on classical knots." *Mathematische Annalen* **270**.1 (1985): 35-45.
>   ([Göttinger Digitalisierungszentrum link to PDF](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/dms/load/img/?PPN=PPN235181684_0270&DMDID=DMDLOG_0010&IDDOC=160813).)

Comment: The *linking number* seems to me somehow related to what you are looking for. See 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi: The linking number tells you about the signed intersections if you pull two components of a link apart. Because of the signs, it can be $0$ even if two components of a link can't be pulled apart, and the knot types of the components don't restrict the linking number at all.

Comment: The Gordian distance is one of the most natural distances you can imagine, but it's also not very well understood as you can probably tell by the references.

Comment: You might be interested in the work by Stasiak (the famous 1/7 writhe guy :-) who made a paper on the, well, I call it "genealogy" of knots. Should be something like Stasiak&Flammini, "Natural classifications of knots". (Oh, and I extended that work long before that paper came out :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *Gordian distance* measures precisely the number of crossings you need to change to turn a knot into another.

MathWorld gives the reference:

Murakami, H. *Some Metrics on Classical Knots*, Math. Ann. **270**, 35--45, 1985.

Comment: I heard about this from Étienne Ghys, who with Gambaudo proved that the set of knots with the Gordian distance contains bi-Lipschitz copies of $\mathbb{Z}^n$: http://archive.numdam.org/ARCHIVE/BSMF/BSMF_2005__133_4/BSMF_2005__133_4_541_0/BSMF_2005__133_4_541_0.pdf

Comment: See also his ICM2006 lecture and references therein http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM2006.1/Main/icm2006.1.0247.0278.ocr.pdf

Comment: The *Gordian distance* is exactly what I sought---Thanks! And so aptly named!

Answer (score 11):

You might be interested in [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.5076) paper of Tim Cochran and Shelly Harvey, which studies the large-scale geometry of various metrics on the set of concordance classes of knots.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to define some distance on knots, you should have a (local) transformation/move on knots or or knot diagrams such that any two knots can be connected by finitely many of them. 
As mentioned by Ryan, the most important local move is crossing change, and the corresponding distance is called the Gordian distance.

Besides of this, **$\sharp$-operation** (H. Murakami, Some metrics on classical knots. Math. Ann. 270, 35-45, 1985), **$\triangle$-operation** (H. Murakami, Y. Nakanishi, On a certain move generating link-homology. Math. Ann. 284, 75-89, 1989) and **$n$-gon move** (H. Aida, Unknotting operation for Polygonal type. Tokyo J. Math. Vol. 15, No. 1, 111-121, 1992) all are unknotting operations, hence can be used to define a distance between knots. Recently, Ayaka Shimizu proved that **region crossing change** is also an unknotting operation for knots (A. Shimizu, Region crossing change is an unknotting operation. J. Math. Soc. Japan. Volume 66, Number 3 (2014), 693-708). While this move depends on the choice of the diagram, hence the distance defined by region crossing change are restricted on minimal diagrams.

On the other hand, there also exist some local operations that we do not know whether it can unknot every knot or not, for example the **4-move** (see problem 1.59 on Kirby's list for more details and Dabkowski and Przytycki's paper: Unexpected connections between Burnside groups and knot theory. Proc Natl Acad Sci U S A. 2004 Dec 14;101(50):17357-60 for some update).

Answer (score 0):

I tried Googling 'Knot distances', but you get a whole load of nautical stuff, which I don't think you meant!

Instead I went for the broader 'Solving knot Polynomials' and found:

[Calculating knot distances and solving tangle equations involving Montesinos links](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=9&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjCpoLL_LDJAhWGPRoKHeayAI0QFghbMAg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fir.uiowa.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D2044%26context%3Detd&usg=AFQjCNFM9zwLHXrJSpeOG531xwfpBf1xwQ&sig2=fV09fJ5xHaPKpINwtaxs0g&bvm=bv.108194040,d.d2s) by Hyeyoung Moon, University of Iowa.

Which comes with a free 35 page suite of programs for you to type in!

Comment: Indeed, searches are distracted by nautical knots.

Comment: This paper was the #4 hit on DuckDuckGo Search with the terms "knot", "distances", and "mathematics"